# Clean up AppBar after process kill

Tags: c#, .net, appbar

I have written an Application Desktop Toolbar (a.k.a AppBar), it works great except for the fact that if I kill the process, the AppBar code never gets a chance to cleanup by sending an ABM_REMOVE. The problem is that this basically screws the users desktop up. The AppBar is written in .NET using interop code.

Does anyone know of a way to clean this resource up, even in the case of a process kill from TaskManager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a process is killed from Task Manager, no events are raised within that application. It's common to use a seperate helper application that listens for the Win32_ProcessStopTrace event for your process. You can use the WqlEventQuery, which is part of System.Management for this.

Here is some example code for this from [a MegaSolutions post](http://www.megasolutions.net/cSharp/Trapping-process-starting-ending_-65911.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Management; 


class ProcessObserver : IDisposable 
{ 
    ManagementEventWatcher m_processStartEvent = null; 
    ManagementEventWatcher m_processStopEvent = null; 


    public ProcessObserver(string processName, EventArrivedEventHandler onStart, EventArrivedEventHandler onStop) 
    { 
        WqlEventQuery startQuery = new WqlEventQuery("Win32_ProcessStartTrace", String.Format("ProcessName='{0}'", processName)); 
        m_processStartEvent = new ManagementEventWatcher(startQuery); 


        WqlEventQuery stopQuery = new WqlEventQuery("Win32_ProcessStopTrace", String.Format("ProcessName='{0}'", processName)); 
        m_processStopEvent = new ManagementEventWatcher(stopQuery); 


        if (onStart != null) 
            m_processStartEvent.EventArrived += onStart; 


        if (onStop != null) 
            m_processStopEvent.EventArrived += onStop; 
    } 


    public void Start() 
    { 
        m_processStartEvent.Start(); 
        m_processStopEvent.Start(); 
    } 


    public void Dispose() 
    { 
        m_processStartEvent.Dispose(); 
        m_processStopEvent.Dispose(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I know this is old but I have the same issue. The code above is helpful but I have not seen much on the internet on how to send the ABM_REMOVE for the correct registration. There could be registrations for other applications and you would not want to close the correct one. My question is this, how do you send the ABM_REMOVE and indicate the correct registration to unregister using the helper process shown above?